# Postfix smtp reject unauthenticated user

Tags: postfix, smtp, authentication

I have configured a mail server with postfix, dovecot, ... The problem is: everyone can connect to my server and send email without authentication. How can i configure postfix, so that all unauthenticated connections will be rejected.

My config in `main.cf` is:

```
##
## TLS Einstellungen
###

tls_ssl_options = NO_COMPRESSION
tls_high_cipherlist = EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!IDEA:!ECDSA:kEDH:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA

### Ausgehende SMTP-Verbindungen (Postfix als Sender)

smtp_tls_security_level = dane
smtp_dns_support_level = dnssec
smtp_tls_policy_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/tls-policy.cf
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_ciphers = high
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

### Eingehende SMTP-Verbindungen

smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/myssl/dh2048.pem
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxx/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxx/privkey.pem


##
## Milter: DKIM-Signaturen durch OpenDKIM-Milter
## und Mail-Filter mit Amavis (via amavisd-milter)
##

milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = unix:/var/run/amavis/amavisd-milter.sock,
                unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock

##
## Server Restrictions für Clients, Empfänger und Relaying
## (im Bezug auf S2S-Verbindungen. Mailclient-Verbindungen werden in master.cf im Submission-Bereich konfiguriert)
##

## Sender
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated


### Bedingungen, damit Postfix als Relay arbeitet (für Clients)
smtpd_relay_restrictions =      reject_non_fqdn_recipient
                                reject_unknown_recipient_domain
                                permit_mynetworks
                                reject_unauth_destination


### check_recipient_access prüft, ob ein account sendonly ist
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,
                               #reject_unauth_destination, 
                               check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/recipient-access.cf


### Bedingungen, die SMTP-Clients erfüllen müssen (sendende Server)
smtpd_client_restrictions =     permit_mynetworks
                                check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/without_ptr
                                reject_unknown_client_hostname

# Clients blockieren, wenn sie versuchen zu früh zu senden
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
```

My configuration in master.cf for mail client:

```
###
### Postscreen-Service: Prüft eingehende SMTP-Verbindungen auf Spam-Server
###
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=no
###
### manual from me (viet)
###
#smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#     -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
###
### SMTP-Daemon hinter Postscreen: Schleift E-Mails zur Filterung durch Amavis 
###
smtpd     pass  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=no
###
### dnsblog führt DNS-Abfragen für Blocklists durch
###
dnsblog   unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
###
### tlsproxy gibt Postscreen TLS support
###
tlsproxy  unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
###
### Submission-Zugang für Clients: Für Mailclients gelten andere Regeln, als für andere Mailserver (siehe smtpd_ in main.cf) 
###
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
    -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
    -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
    -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
    -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
    -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/sender-login-maps.cf
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_sender_login_mismatch,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    -o smtpd_helo_required=no
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
    -o cleanup_service_name=submission-header-cleanup
```

In dovecot i have already configured a service for authentication:

```
service auth {
    ### Auth socket für Postfix
    unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
        mode = 0660
        user = postfix
        group = postfix
    }

    ### Auth socket für LMTP-Dienst
    unix_listener auth-userdb {
        mode = 0660
        user = vmail
        group = vmail
    }
}
```

The log during sending a mail without authentication looks like that:

```
Aug 23 11:25:15 mail postfix/postscreen[4014]: CONNECT from [xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:xxxx to [x.x.x.x]:25
Aug 23 11:25:15 mail postfix/postscreen[4014]: WHITELISTED [x.x.x.x]:xxxx
Aug 23 11:25:15 mail postfix/postscreen[4014]: warning: cannot connect to service private/smtpd: Connection refused
Aug 23 11:34:36 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[4100]: connect from gate.xxxxx.xxxx.de[x.x.x.x]
Aug 23 11:34:36 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[4100]: 5A60B400CF: client=gate.xxxxx.xxxx.de[x.x.x.x]
Aug 23 11:34:36 mail postfix/cleanup[4103]: 5A60B400CF: message-id=<abcb10b6-96b1-06e9-0e25-2c477a9631ae@mydomain>
Aug 23 11:34:36 mail amavis[3384]: (03384-02) Passed CLEAN {AcceptedOutbound}, AM.PDP-SOCK/ORIGINATING LOCAL [x.xx.x.x] [x.x.x.x] <myemail@mydomain> -> <receicer@email>, Queue-ID: 5A60B400CF, Message-ID: <abcb10b6-96b1-06e9-0e25-2c477a9631ae@qvpham.com>, mail_id: 8qu_TyPN6ZBY, Hits: -, size: 516, 16 ms
Aug 23 11:34:36 mail opendkim[2794]: 5A60B400CF: gate.xxxxx.xxxx.de [x.x.x.x] not internal
Aug 23 11:34:36 mail opendkim[2794]: 5A60B400CF: not authenticated
Aug 23 11:34:36 mail postfix/qmgr[3371]: 5A60B400CF: from=<myemail@mydomain>, size=357, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 23 11:34:36 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[4100]: disconnect from gate.xxxxx.xxxx.de[x.x.x.x] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=7
Aug 23 11:34:37 mail postfix/smtp[4105]: 5A60B400CF: to=<myemail@mydomain>, relay=receiver.server[x.x.x.x]:25, delay=1.1, delays=0.16/0.03/0.36/0.54, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10035): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 56FEC80008E)
Aug 23 11:34:37 mail postfix/qmgr[3371]: 5A60B400CF: removed
```

**UPDATE**

**It works now, when i remove the `permit_mynetworks` in `-o smtpd_sender_restrictions`. Is `permit_mynetworks` not only for *localhost*.**

After executing of `postconf -d | grep mynetworks` i got:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 172.31.16.0/20 [::1]/128 [fe80::]/64
```

Comment: Postfix has better than average documentation; there's a whole README devoted to authentication including using Dovecot: http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html

Comment: Thanks! I'm reading it. The docu is very useful. But it would be faster if someone can help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you havent configure the user backend for the sasl authentication on postfix.

```
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
```

That tells postfix to use dovecot for user authentication.

In dovecot you have to enable a new service listener for postfix

```
# vim /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf
```

and add something like this:

```
service auth {
    unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
        group = postfix
        mode = 0660
        user = postfix
   }
}
```

restart both services and test it

Comment: I have configured this service in dovecot before. But it didn't work too. I have added syslog in my question

Comment: @julivico I dont see smtpd_sasl_type setting in your postfix mail.conf file

Comment: I have configured it in `master.cf`. I have added `master.cf` in my question. You can find it under `submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd`.

Comment: @julivico selinux maybe ?

Comment: can you explain me more about that. I don't know selinux. My O.S is ubuntu 16.

Comment: It works now, when i remove the configuration `permit_mynetworks`. Is `permit_mynetworks` not only for **localhost**? My server runs in Amazon AWS and my client runs at my home.

Comment: @julivico permit_networks is a definition of networks that you want to permit. In restrictions you declare the policy order you want. Permit those networks before everything else, will do exactly that and will ignore any other restriction. Well done for figure this out.